# How to obtain datas from mongoDB by using Node.js codes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I have got in trouble with how to get data from MongoDB;
It seems that my program works, but it does not have any data, so please give me your ideas to solve this.
Here are js files.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const WordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    English: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    Japanese: {
        type: String,
    },

    Note: {
        type: String,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("wordtables", WordSchema);
```

From the above code, I expect these values below:

{"_id":{"$oid":"6404b35780fbb3e51f2afc20"},
"English":"Spain",
"Japanese":"スペイン",
"Note":"conntry"},

{"_id":{"$oid":"6404b37c80fbb3e51f2afc21"},
"English":"Germany",
"Japanese":"ドイツ",
"Note":"country"},

{"_id":{"$oid":"6405da0c6908722bbf92b5f1"},
"English":"the United Kingdom",
"Japanese":"イギリス",
"Note":"I want to go there"}

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const wordtables = require('./models/WordTable');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(3000, console.log("Go!!"));



mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://
(my id and pw)
@cluster0.ourgdrv.mongodb.net/test"
).then(()=>
    console.log("Connecting")
)
.catch ((err)=>console.log("error"));

// API Goes
app.get("http://localhost:3000/", async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        const allWords = await wordtables.find();
        res.status(200).json(allWords);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("error1")
    }
});
```

```
let table = document.getElementById("writeHere");

const get_Words = async () =>{
    const getDB = axios.get("http://localhost:3000/")
    .then(() => {
        let data = Object.entries(getDB);
        console.log(data);
        let words = data.map((word) => {
        let [English, Japanese] = word;
        console.log(English, Japanese);
        table.innerHTML= words;
    })
})};
get_Words();
```

I am new to handling MongoDB, so I am very grateful if you would give me a comment.
Thanks in advance so much

I would like to have datas from MongoDB to the script.js file.
Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: what is the response you get ?

Comment: Thank you for your quickest advice. Currently, the response says: script.js:7 []length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without the response you get but here is a few things :

Firstly, in your `backend`, you should remove the base URL from the `app.get()` method, so the route becomes simply `"/"`:

```
app.get("/", async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        const allWords = await wordtables.find();
        res.status(200).json(allWords);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("error1")
    }
});
```

Secondly, in your `frontend`, you're not waiting for the response from the server before handling the data. Use `await` and then use the response data :

```
const get_Words = async () =>{
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/");
        const data = response.data;
        console.log(data);
        let words = data.map((word) => {
            let English = word.English;
            let Japanese = word.Japanese;
            let row = `<tr><td>${English}</td><td>${Japanese}</td></tr>`;
            return row;
        });
        table.innerHTML = words.join('');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
    }
};

get_Words()
```

Comment: I thank you for your kind suppport. There is one error after I followed your advice, saying error:  "TypeError: data.map is not a function" at get_Words (script.js:8:26).  I think that the map method will work only for an array variable. Would it be right?

Comment: Yes of course. If it is an object you can do `Object.keys(data)`

Comment: With your kindest help, I made a progress.  But I still need to have a problem; When I write, my Index.html returns. ```const data = response.data;```  From this point, I would like you to share your ideas to let HTML have a data row.

Comment: Now, here is current script.js:  ```let data = response.data;
        console.log(data);
    
        // console.log(data);
        let words = data.map((word) => {
            let English = word.English;
            console.log(English);
            let Japanese = word.Japanese;
            let row = `<tr><td>${English}</td><td>${Japanese}</td></tr>`;
            console.log(row);
            return row;
        });
        table.innerHTML = words.join('');```  Console.log(English) has not shown data from MongoDB.

Comment: You should open a new question and explain it with clear code. Hard to tell in the comments